# How to have only unique values in a View

Tags: views

I created a view that lists all comments on a particular node (This was achieved using the contextual filters).

I send notifications to users on the list when a comment is added to the node.

The issue is that for users that have made more than one (1) comment to the node, they get multiple notifications.

My question is that is there a way to ensure that each user appears only once in my view, irrespective of the number of times they make a comment to a node.

Thank you.

Comment: If I were you, when a new comment is added, I would notify everyone except the new comment author.

Comment: It sounds like you need to use aggregation in your view. Aggregate by Count on comment uid or something like that.

Comment: @NoSssweat, I am able to exclude the new comment author. @j, reynolds, i guess that would be in the "filter criteria" section? Thanks

Comment: @seyi, to turn on Aggregate, it's under ADVANCED.

Comment: I turned on the aggregate. What i was wondering is if to add the "comment uid" field under "Filter criteria" or "Contextual filters". I have tried adding it under Filter criteria with various options but its not working yet. Thanks.